# Can't get the hang of FormData and ngResource

Tags: angularjs, ngresource

I'm trying to upload a file as MIME/multipart via AngularJS 1.6.4 and then send it off to an ASP.Net WebAPI. I have referenced a sample project that uses version 1.3.1, where the following works:

```
 var formData = new FormData(); 

 angular.forEach(photos, function (photo) { 
      formData.append(photo.name, photo); 
 }); 

 return photoManagerClient.save(formData) 
                                    .$promise 
                                    .then(function (result) { 
                                        if (result && result.photos) { 
                                            result.photos.forEach(function (photo) { 
                                                if (!photoExists(photo.name)) { 
                                                    service.photos.push(photo); 
                                                } 
                                            }); 
                                        } 
.
.
.
function photoManagerClient($resource) { 
    return $resource("api/photo/:fileName", 
            { id: "@fileName" }, 
            { 
                'save': { method: 'POST', transformRequest: angular.identity, headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined } }
            }); 
}
```

I can't get this to work using 1.6.4 and I can't find the reason. The MIME/multipart header isn't there with 1.6.4, so I have been reading the bytes directly from the content, and yet I can't get the filename in this way.

It's obvious that the FormData is actually making it across because I can access the bytes in the request.

I have seen other answers/docs advise adding a transformRequest function because otherwise the Content-Type defaults to JSON. But when I do this, that code does not execute so the file is missing from the request on the server side.

I'm a bit lost here and was hoping there was an obvious reason for this difference between 1.3.1 and 1.6.4 that someone could point me toward.

Edit to add request headers:

Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:31761
Content-Type:application/json;charset=utf-8
Host:localhost:40981
Origin:http://localhost:51609
Referer:http://localhost:51609/app/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3266.0 Safari/537.36

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `header request` at `Network` in dev-tools, maybe it useful.
If is not work, paste the `header reuqest` maybe can provide more information.

Comment: Added above in edit. It does seem to default to json but this appears to be a new behavior that wasn't present as of 1.3.1 and I haven't determined a working way to override it.

Comment: @barthooper `Content-Type:application/json;charset=utf-8` Content-type still in requeset.header, so you should delete it.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried setting the Content-Type to application/x-www-form-urlencoded instead of undefined but it still reverts to json. I'm convinced that's not the way to handle it however as nearly every other answer I've come across has it set to undefined.

Comment: Maybe you can use `$http` instead of `$resource`. `$http` can set header, https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: Yup, that's the ticket. I didn't even need to set the header. Apparently the key was just sending the FormData directly in $http post.